# How to remove child element from div

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting error some this like this.

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node':
>   parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

my div is some what like this.

```
<div class="" style="" id ="P1">
    <div class= " " style="" id ="C1">
        <Input>Val</Input>
    </div>
    <div class= " child2" style="" id ="C2">
        <Input>Val2</Input>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to remove all the child but getting the error.

```
var myClass = val.("Data").el.dom // My Parent div
    myClass.removeChild();
```

Here is what I am trying. Can anybody help me how to get this.

Comment: In dom element. Wanted to remove from dom.

Comment: `Data` is id of my component.

Comment: are you using jquery ? in which event you want to remove all child div ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove all the child of `div` with id P1 you may simply do this :

```js
document.querySelector("#P1").innerHTML = "";

//or use this 
//document.getElementById("P1").innerHTML = "";

//or a jQuery solution like this
// $('#P1').html("");
```

```html
<div class="" style="" id="P1">
  <div class=" child1" style="" id="C1">
    <Input>Val</Input>
  </div>
  <div class=" child2" style="" id="C2">
    <Input>Val2</Input>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am only able to access id not class

Answer (score 0):

[**removeChild**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) method removes a specific child node.If need to remove all the child ,put it in a while loop

firstChild returns the first nested element. On successful removal, the next child will be the first child,so as long as firstChild is there, it will execute

```js
var prtElement = document.getElementById('P1');
while (prtElement.firstChild) {
  prtElement.removeChild(prtElement.firstChild);
}
```

```html
<div class="Parent" style="" id="P1">
  <div class=" child1" style="" id="C1">
    <Input>Val</Input>
  </div>
  <div class=" child2" style="" id="C2">
    <Input>Val2</Input>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
/* or whatever else function you want */
$("#parent").children().remove();
});
```